# My Site Shrinks When Deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, heroku

Check it out, in this quick video I toggle between my localhost copy and the deployed app on Heroku: http://screencast.com/t/oD6SLXHg99k

Obviously both are in the same browser.  Why would this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you did not change the zoom with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> at some point in time and your browser remembered it? Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to reset it.

Comment: You're right.  This is embarrassing.  I thought I had opened fresh tabs for both but apparently not.  I wonder if I can remove this question from the archives :)